# Read file in Scala : Stream closed

Tags: scala

I try to read a file in scala like this:

```
def parseFile(filename: String) = {
  val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename)
  try {
    val lines = source.getLines().map(line => line.trim.toDouble)
    return lines
  } catch {
    // re-throw exception, but make source source is closed
    case
      t: Throwable => {
      println("error during parsing of file")
      throw t
    }
  } finally {
    source.close()
  }
}
```

When I access the result later, I get an

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
```

I understand that this arises because `source.getLines()` only returns an (lazy) `Iterator[String]`, and I already close the `BufferedSource` in the `finally` clause.

How can I avoid this error, i.e. how can a "evaluate" the Stream before closing the source?

EDIT: I tried to call `source.getLines().toSeq` which did not help.

Comment: You could return a list instead of an iterator. Just do `return lines.toList`.

Comment: @marstran I tried with toSeq which did not work (runtime type was still Stream). With toList, it works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, you can try the following solution, which makes the codes more functional and takes the advantage of lazy evaluation.

First, define a helper function `using`, which takes care of open/close the file.

```
def using[A <: {def close() : Unit}, B](param: A)(f: A => B): B =
    try f(param) finally param.close()
```

Then, you can refactor your code in functional programming style:

```
using(Source.fromFile(filename)) {
  source =>
    val lines = Try(source.getLines().map(line => line.trim.toDouble))
    val result = lines.flatMap(l => Try(processOrDoWhatYouWantForLines(l)))
    result.get
}
```

Actually, the `using` function can be used for handling all resources which need to be closed at the end of the operation.

Comment: FYI anonymous trait will result in a reflection lookup, which could impact the performance. You can use `java.lang.AutoClosable`

Answer (score 1):

List is not lazy so change:

```
val lines = source.getLines().map(line => line.trim.toDouble)
```

to

```
val lines = source.getLines().toList.map(line => line.trim.toDouble)
```

in order to force computing.